# Why LINQ returns other column value than expected?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

My goal is to retrieve ParentTypeId for single ParentId.
I keep searching and trying varius approaches
**but I end up all my queries return ParentId rather than ParentTypeId**.

My model has these 2 tables:

```
public class Parent
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Index("ParentIdIndex", IsUnique = true)]
    public int ParentId  { get; set; }

    public string ParentName {get; set;}

    public virtual ParentType ParentType { get; set; }
}

public class ParentType 
{

    [Key, ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public int ParentTypeId { get; set; }

    public string ParentTypeName { get; set; }

    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

This SQL query returns correct result:

```
select 
ParentId,
ParentType_ParentTypeId
FROM [myDB].[dbo].[Parents]
Where ParentId = 5
```

Which is one row: (ParentId = 5, ParentTypeId = 6)

But when use LINQ query in c# method it returns ParentId value,
not ParentTypeId value.

```
        var query = (
                    from t1 in db.Parents
                    where (t1.ParentId == ParentId)
                    select t1.ParentType.ParentTypeId
                    ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Why?

Comment: Your query seems to be right, it's probably in the code you didn't provided or the data you're using. (multiple rows having the searched ParentId)

Comment: *Why?* Because you setup a [Shared Primary Key Association](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations), hence `ParentTypeId` is always the same as `ParentId` (at least from EF point of view based on your configuration).

Comment: The more interesting question would be, why is there a `ParentType_ParentTypeId` column in your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created foreign key incorrectly.

`ParentTypeId` must be foreign key of `Parent` table.

And primary table must be `ParentType`.

See my example:

`Parent` class

```
public class Parent
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Index("ParentIdIndex", IsUnique = true)]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public string ParentName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentType")]
    public int ParentTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual ParentType ParentType{ get; set; }
}
```

and `ParentType` class

```
public class ParentType
{
    [Key]
    public int ParentTypeId { get; set; }

    public string ParentTypeName { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
}
```

You can get ParentTypeId easily like this

```
var parentItem = (
                from t1 in db.Parents
                where (t1.ParentId == 12345)
                select t1
                ).FirstOrDefault();
// parentItem.ParentTypeId
```

Comment: Ok we are getting somewhere. I applied almost all your thoughts except IEnumerable is ICollection in my project. (don't know the difference).
Now when I try to insert new Parent I always get new ParentType. Is there a way to assign existing ParentType to new Parent being inserted?

Comment: just assign parentObject.ParentTypeId  = existingParentTypeId before inserting